# Duplicate plugins installed on the eclipse for C/C++ IDE

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded the newest version of `Eclipse for C/C++ Development`(`Photon Release Candidate 3 (4.8.0RC3)`), then I wanted to remove some of the installed plugins to keep it as light as possible.

Looking through the installed plugins, I noticed that there are duplicate entries in the listed installed plugins.
So we you see the `CDT` plugins on the first level, then they are present also inside the `Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers`.
[image]

Any reason to have those duplicates?
Should I remove the from the first level? Or the ones inside the `Eclipse IDE for C/C++ development`?

Comment: This is a hierarchical tree expressing dependencies of what's been explicitly installed, not a simple list. Check your file system, you shouldn't find actual duplicates.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the _Installation Details_ dialog, right? The _Installed Software_ tab shows the installed features, not the installed plug-ins. A feature defines a set of plug-ins and other features. In the tab _Plug-ins_ a list of all installed plug-ins is shown.

Comment: @howlger You are right, it's the `Installation Details` dialog. I understood now, it's just a dependency hierarchical view, but the plugins are not installed multiple times. Thanks!

Comment: @nitind Thank you for the explanation, you are right, there aren't. It was just a bit confusing for me. You can add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hierarchical tree expressing dependencies of what's been explicitly installed, not a simple list. It looks fine. Check your file system if you like, but you shouldn't find actual duplicates.